# Can you get married if you already have a child?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have an Amulet of Mara, but the priest doesn't have the dialog option for marriage.

I have the Hearthfire and Dawnguard DLCs and have adopted one child. Help?

Answer (score 2):

You should still be able to get married even if you already have a child. Both the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Notes) and the [TES wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage#Married_life) mentions instances of your spouse also adopting your children which you had before you were married.

Check if you have completed the requirements for marriage:

> You will not be able to marry anyone until you have spoken to Maramal
>   about marriage, even if you have already obtained an amulet from
>   somewhere else. [Maramal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Maramal) can be found in the Temple of Mara, but will
>   also spend time in the Bee and Barb.
>
> When you approach an [eligible NPC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#NPCs_available_to_be_married), they may mention the amulet you are
>   wearing. In order for this option to become available, you must
>   complete their objective. Even if a character is flagged as
>   marriageable, the Radiant AI system may not allow you to marry said
>   character even if you have completed their objective, so it's best to
>   have at least one backup candidate.
>
> You can then ask if they are interested. They will respond and ask if
>   you are interested as well. If you say yes, you can then proceed to
>   marriage. In order to complete the event, you will now need to travel
>   back to the [Temple of Mara](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Temple_of_Mara) in Riften and arrange the event. Then you
>   need to talk to your spouse (who will be waiting by the doors of the Temple of Mara).

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "Skyrim - Marriage" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage)</sup>